# MvvmCross: Unit-testing services with plugins

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am creating a cross-platform project with MvvmCross v3 and Xamarin solution and i would like to create some unit-tests.
[This](http://slodge.blogspot.co.il/2012/10/testing-viewmodels-in-mvvmcross.html) seems a bit outdated, so i was trying to follow [this](https://github.com/slodge/BallControl/blob/master/Cirrious.Sphero.WorkBench/Cirrious.Sphero.WorkBench.Core.Test/ViewModels/HomeViewModelTest.cs) and it worked as expected.

However, I am now making an attempt to unit-test some of my domain services, which are dependent on platform specific MvvvCross plugins (e.g `ResourceLoader`).

Running the test results in the following exception:

```
Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to resolve type   
Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins.IMvxPluginManager.
```

I assume that `IMvxPluginManager` is probably registered in the Setup flow, and that I need to include platform implementation of the plugins in my project, yet I was wondering what would be the preferred way of setting up my unit-test project? Is there something that I am missing?

Is there any updated tutorial for the above task?

Are there already any plugin platform extensions that supports test environment, or should I make an attempt to write them by myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't be loading the plugins or a real `MvxPluginManager` during your service tests.

Instead your unit tests should be registering mock types for the interfaces that your services need to use.

```
var mock = new Mock<INeedToUse>();
// use mock.Setup methods
Ioc.RegisterSingleton<INeedToUse>(mock.Object);
// or you can use constructor dependency injection on INeedToUse instead
```

You can also register a mock `IMvxPluginManager` if you really need to, but in the majority of cases I don't believe you should need that. If you've got a case where you absolutely need it, please post a code sample - it's easier to talk in code than text.

Comment: Hi Stuart, Thanks, I will make an attempt to create mocks. Isn't creating a mock for, let's say IMvxPluginManager, is actually the same as implementing the "Plugin" for a unit-tests project? Assuming That my service under test should actually be loading a resource file...

Comment: Without seeing your service I'm not sure - but generally I'd personally prefer just to serve a string from c# in my test rather than adding a resource file and relying on a test plugin. If you do want to write a mock plugin you can - maybe my 'you shouldn't' answer was to strongly worded - maybe more like 'I wouldn't'

Comment: What if you really want to test the real plugin? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

This scenario should be well possible. I wanted to UnitTest my SqlLite service implementation. I did the following to get it to work:

- Create a Visual Studio unit test project
- Add a reference to .Core portable library project
- Add a nuget reference To MvvmCross Test Helper
- Add a nugget reference to MvvmCross SqlLite Plugin
  ( this will make use of the WPF implementation of SqlLite)

Download the SqlLite windows library and copy these into your test project
[Sql Lite Download location](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)
And make sure to add the sqllite3.dll to the root of your unit test project and set the "Copy to Output Library" to "Copy always". This will make sure the actual sqllite database is copied to the unit test dll location. (Check that the DLL is copied to your bin/debug folder)

Then write you unit test the following way:

```
[TestClass]
public class SqlServiceTests:MvxIoCSupportingTest
{
    private readonly ISQLiteConnectionFactory _factory;

    public SqlServiceTests()
    {
        base.ClearAll();

        _factory = new MvxWpfSqLiteConnectionFactory();
        Ioc.RegisterSingleton<ISQLiteConnectionFactory>(_factory);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void YourSqlLiteTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var si = new SqlDataService(_factory);
        var list = si.GetOrderList();
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this with my viewmodel. By using the IoC.RegisterSingleton method the SqlConnectionFactory should be readyli available for your viewmodels.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I'm one of those guys who just doesn't do unit testing the "right way", but it works for me. Specifically, I like to use SQLite in ":memory:" mode to run tests against actual data (loaded at test runtime). When I tried to specify ":memory:" as the db name, it complained that it can't create the database at C:\Users\...